Spyder Update has broken the kernel on Chromebook
I recently updated my Spyder to the newest version on my Chromebook and now I am getting
"An error occurred while starting the kernel
The Python environment or installation whose interpreter is located at
/home/
doesn't have spyder‑kernels version >=3.0.0,<3.1.0 installed."
I have tried to follow the documentation but so far nothing has worked. For reference I have tried pip install spyder-kernels==3.0.* and I have even tried uninstalling and reinstalling spyder. I can open and run on the 'base' terminal but I have no idea if I should do that or not. Any suggestions on what to try next?

Figured it out just had to change the interpreter to internal
